# return !!( proto === null || proto.constructor === Object );

Tags: javascript

Just trying to understand, that what should following line return & how if `proto.constructor = Object`?

```
return !!( proto === null || proto.constructor === Object );
```

More specifically, how `!!` works?

Comment: `!!` is a quick way of saying "make sure we return a boolean and convert all truthy values to `true` and all falsy values to `false`".

Comment: Depends where you put it. And what `proto` is

Comment: Why I'm getting many down votes?

Comment: @RuntimeException "How !! works" has been asked and answered before in SO. Moreover we have no idea what "proto" is, where do you define it? (I didn't downvote btw, but I _did_ close vote since you're not being clear here)

Comment: `!!` is totally useless here because the expression always does return booleans already (or throw exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return a boolean value: true or false. `!!` works as double-flipping: if a value is false, you flip it to true, then you flip it back to false. Basically, having `!!` is the same as not having `!!`.

True if `proto === null` or `proto.constructor === Object`.

False iff `proto !== null` and `proto.constructor !== Object`.

Therefore if `proto.constructor = Object`, it will return true.

Answer (score 1):

The [`!` (Logical NOT)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) operator

> Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.<sub>(MDN)</sub>

Answer (score -3):

an typeError. because proto is not defined and not equal to null so js will try to get attribute "constructor" from proto that do not exist.

Comment: How do you know `proto` is not defined?

Comment: Well, it certainly isn't defined by the question. However, by `typeError`, I think you mean `ReferenceError`. Specifically, `ReferenceError: proto is not defined`.

Comment: The code in question is obviously just a part of a script where `proto` might be defined.

Comment: @meagar `return` would cause an `SyntaxError` even before the `ReferenceError`

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Ah, true. You have out-pedantic'd me.

Comment: Oh, as a follow-up though, JS will definitely *not* try to get the "constructor" attribute of `proto` if `proto` is not defined; `proto === null` will raise an exception first.